# Android accessing asset file

Tags: android, android-assets

I want to access a text file located under assets from a class that would do some processing on that file and is invoked in my Activity. The code I am using is:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream instream = assetManager.open("file.txt");
```

this works fine if used in an Activity class but how to make it work in a plain java class?

Edited

JamesBlack - because if i pass the inputstream then the following code won't work

```
for (int i = 0; i < gestureNumbers.size(); i++) {
   BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
   // possible error here
   while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {  ...  }
}
```

Even if the gestureNumbers.size() > 1 then the while loop is executed only once and then it equals null once it read the file once.

When the following code works but I can't open the file in plain java class, it works in activity class and I don't want to have too much code in one class.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gestureNumbers.size(); i++) {
   InputStream instream = assetManager.open("BSL_Word_POS.txt");
   BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
   // possible error here
   while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Why not pass the InputStream to the plain java class.  Why do you not want to do this in the Activity?

Comment: if you want to do in plain java class then pass the context of activity class to ur java class and then context.getAssets();
 will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the context to that java class to access the asset folder.

Comment: Can you give an example please

Comment: NextClass nextview = new NextClass(current_activity.this);  
public class NextClass{
    public NextClass(Context context){
     AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
   InputStream instream = assetManager.open("file.txt");
}